# How to handle Zend Framework tags that do not clearly convey Framework version?

Tags: discussion, tags

SO now has an accumulated body of knowledge for various issues concerning Zend Framework of various versions.

Versions 2 and 3 are a lot more similar to each other, but they are fairly different from version 1.  So different in fact that they are not interchangeable. For example, when it comes to forms, version 1 uses `Zend_Form()` and Decorators, Version 2+ uses `\Zend\Form()` and has no Decorators.

**Question**

How do I handle this?

Do I tag my Version 2 questions with generic [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) tag?  or [zend-framework2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework2) only?  Or both?  When I see [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) tag do I understand that it is talking about version 1?  or it may refer to 1, 2, and 3?

What about [zend-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-form)?  The situation is the same.  [zend-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-form) version 1 (or does it refer to all) is much different from [zend-form2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-form2)

**Examples:**

(tagged zend-framework zend-form)
[Appending or Prepending HTML Tags to Zend Form Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848188/appending-or-prepending-html-tags-to-zend-form-element)
It is version 1 from looking at it

(tagged zend-framework zend-form)
[Zend Framework - Form View Helper, div tag error didn't show correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777307/zend-framework-form-view-helper-div-tag-error-didnt-show-correctly)
Unclear what version (do we assume "latest" or 1? or 2? or 3?)

(tagged zend-framework zend-form)
[zf2/zf3 Hydrate Multiple Fieldsets with Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479777/zf2-zf3-hydrate-multiple-fieldsets-with-objects)
Refers to 2, and 3, but tags don't mention any specific version

Comment: Why not just fold them into one? Like the one ring...

Comment: folding into one is probably not a good idea .. -> i.e. right now when I am looking for `zend-form2` material I want to see `zend-form2`.  If it is all rolled up into one (i.e. `zend-form`) I have to sort through version 1 and 2, which is what I originally wanted to avoid.  Avoiding the mish-mash is a key idea to my post

Comment: Why you need so? Isn't the same more or less some functions? What happened to backwards/forward compatibility?

Comment: not really - ZF2 has been redesigned a lot.  Some things I'm sure hold, but a lot has really been drastically redesigned and changed.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your dilemma. You're going to have to use context to determine which it means. Here's what I would suggest

- [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) - This refers to ZF in general. If there are no version tags with it, assume it means ZF1
- [zend-framework2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework2) - Use with ZF2
- [zend-framework3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework3) - Use with ZF3
- [zend-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-form) - If it has a [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) tag, it refers to Zend Form 1. If it has no [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) tag, it means Zend Form in general.
- [zend-form2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-form2) - Refers only to Zend Form 2. Should use a [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) tag

Comment: thanks.  I think the issue is in part that some questions may be about ZF in general and some may be about ZF1 specifically.  ZF1 + ZF general are currently merged into a single tag ZF.  I think for my purposes though I will avoid using the generic term from now on at least for my own posts when I have a specific version in mind. I rather be specific.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to have separate [tag:zend-framework1] and [tag:zend-framework] tags?

Comment: @Dennis If we were talking new tags, then yes. But 1. ZF1 is old 2. You'd have a hard time trying to retag everything ZF1. I think you should leave it as-is